# How to index an array of BigIntegers by BigIntegers

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, biginteger

I'm trying to build an array of BigIntegers, but it seems like the array needs to be indexed by integers themselves (and if true, that seems extremely stupid to me but I'm hoping I'm just misunderstanding something). What I'm trying is the essentially the following:

```
BigInteger totalChoiceFunctions = BigInteger.valueOf(50031545098999704);
BigInteger[][] choiceFunctions = new BigInteger[totalChoiceFunctions][36];
```

But this causes the error "type mismatch: cannot convert from BigInteger to int". In order to remedy this I tried:

```
BigInteger[][] choiceFunctions = new BigInteger[totalChoiceFunctions.intValue()][36];
```

however this doesn't seem to help. When I compile and run I get the runtime error of:

```
exception in thread 'main' java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
```

Confused, I looked at the oracle documentation for the intValue() method of BigInteger and found that "if this BigInteger is too big to fit in an int, only the low-order 32 bits are returned. Note that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude of the BigInteger value as well as return a result with the opposite sign". I suspect this is what's going on, considering that 50031545098999704 is certainly too big for int (and why I turned towards an array of BigIntegers since I want my array to be indexed by the numbers from 1 to 50031545098999704).

If my understanding is correct, then:

```
BigInteger[][] chioceFunctions = new BigInteger[totalChoiceFunctions][36];
```

creates an array which *stores* BigIntegers but is still *indexed* by ints. How can I make an array that both stores and is indexed by BigIntegers? Is it possible? Note that the code I'm using this for might in this case be able to work if I use longs rather than ints to index, but I want it to scale to a size where I'll be forced to index by BigIntegers. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I'm curious why this seems stupid?  The value of your index only determines the number of the object that you can store.  If you need to store more, create your own container...

Comment: Even ignoring the limits of Java arrays, you do not have the memory for a 50 quadrillion by 36 array of BigIntegers.

Comment: Gee ow much memory do you have you need at least `50031545098999704 * 64 * 36 `

Comment: If you really want an array that's indexed by integers so large that you need `BigInteger`, I suspect that what you really want is some kind of `Map`.  I'm assuming this would be a sparse array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays in java are not sparse, so your array would need about 200 000 terabyte (not including the referenced arrays/BigIntegers). So no, currently not possible. There are some plans to support long as index in arrays with maybe java 10 (certainly not java9).

I guess you actually want a sparse datastructure; a Map<BigInteger,BigInteger> or as you have a nested array Map<Tuple<BigInteger,Integer>, BigInteger> should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. In java, all arrays are indexed by integers only.

Answer (score 3):

In theory (but not practical), you can create such a class.

An ordinary array can't increase its size dynamically, right? But `ArrayList` can! How can it do that? Well, by recreating a new array with a larger size when the capacity is full.

You can kind of apply the same logic here.

An ordinary array cannot hold 50031545098999704 items. *But* you can create *multiple* arrays to hold them!

So in your class, you should have a matrix:

```
public class BigIntegerArray<T> {
    private T[][] innerMatrix;
}
```

The constructor is going to accept a number as the array length, right? Using the array length, you know how many arrays you need. For example, if the array size is N where `Integer.MAX_VALUE < N <= Integer.MAX_VALUE * 2`, you know that you should initialize the inner matrix like this:

```
innerMatrix = new T[2][Integer.MAX_VALUE];
```

Just use some maths!

And you would want to implement a `get` and `set` method. If the index is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` but smaller than or equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE * 2`, access it like this:

```
innerArray[1][index - Integer.MAX_VALUE]; // not real code. I'm just illustrating the point.
```

You get what I mean? It's basically simple maths.

EDIT:

Maybe I didn't explain this well enough. The algorithm of creating the inner matrix is like this: (pseudocode)

```
if arraySize is smaller than Integer.MAX_VALUE then
    create an array of size arraySize
    return
initialize a variable counter to 0
while arraySize > 0
    subtract Integer.MAX_VALUE from arraySize
    increment counter
create an array with the array size of counter
```

The accessing part is similar:

```
if index is smaller than Integer.MAX_VALUE then
    access [0][index]
    return
initialize a variable counter to 0
while arraySize > 0
    subtract Integer.MAX_VALUE from arraySize
    increment counter
access [counter][index - Integer.MAX_VALUE * counter]
```

Answer (score 1):

Java will only let you index by `int` the maximum index that you can achieve is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which is 1 byte short of 2 GB which is 2147483647. Your array can not hold numbers greater than this.

You should be using a data structure which scales more than `int` limits, e.g. `maps`.  `Maps` will behave like a `2D Array` only without any limit, here you can store them as :-

```
Map m = new HashMap<BigInteger,BigInteger>();
```

The insertion and retrieval will be a little harder as compared to simple `2D array` but considering the limitations of indexes using only `int` we have to go with another approach.